# ffmpeg video to jpg frames poor quality

Tags: ffmpeg

The quality of JPGs extracted by ffmpeg from an mp4 is much poorer than pause frame from video player (vlc). I am looking for ffmpeg cmd option to improve output quality.

Using following cmd :

```
/home/tools/bin/ffmpeg -i Merkurtransit_20191111_crf20_8fps_crop.mp4 Merkurtransit_20191111_crf20_8fps_crop_%04d.jpg -hide_banner
```

The ffmpeg cmd is from instructions found here :
    https://www.bugcodemaster.com/article/extract-images-frame-frame-video-file-using-ffmpeg

A comparing screen copy is here:
    http://skywatcher.space/download/vlc_player_vs_ffmpeg_bug.png

A few items of note. I created the mp4 myself from high res png (actually originally from 16bit tiff) using ffmpeg :

```
/home/tools/bin/ffmpeg -framerate 8.0 -i ./AS_P10_RS6_png_reg/Merkurtransit_20191111_%03d.png -vf "crop=760:560:20:40" -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 20 -r 24 -y ./Video/Merkurtransit_20191111_crf20_8fps_crop.mp4
```

The crf 20 is pretty high quality, close to 100% and the recovered frame should be close to original. The video player pause frame shows adequate quality. (though I can't say if it is on a key frame or not)

ffmpeg version info:

```
home/tools/bin/ffmpeg -v
ffmpeg version N-80251-g0c7fa15 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)
  configuration: --prefix=/home/tools/ffmpeg_build --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-cflags=-I/home/tools/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/home/tools/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/home/tools/bin --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      55. 24.100 / 55. 24.100
  libavcodec     57. 45.100 / 57. 45.100
  libavformat    57. 37.101 / 57. 37.101
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 46.101 /  6. 46.101
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
```

Answer (score 2):

FFmpeg is primarily a *video* convertor and JPEG output is the result of a MJPEG encoder generating a single image. When no rate control parameters are set, a default bitrate of 200 kbps is selected.

For a better quality output, use

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -q:v 1 -qmin 1 -qmax 1 out%d.jpg
```

The quantizer is clamped to exactly 1.

Comment: How can I change the output maximum size of the jpg? I only want a mix size of 200kb.

Comment: Note: I'm noticing (in very limited testing) that PNG will produce noticeably better quality than the highest JPG quality. I'm not noticing artifacts in my samples but am noticing that small details are lost by JPG.

Comment: Photo and video codecs (of which JPEG is one) are not meant to be lossless, only perceptually acceptable in normal viewing conditions (not pixel peeking).